# Removing a module currently in use

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to remove a module currently in use in linux. Module name is say i915 (display module)
`rmmod i915` shows `Module currently in use.`
Similar output using `rmmod -f i915` and it is not dependent on any module. How to go about doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i915 is currently being used by some user-space application, such as the X server. You'll have to shut down whatever is using it before you can remove the module.

Comment: I have understood that we need to close the applications currently using that module. I was wondering if we can forcefully do something like this. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: In general, you can't force a module to unload; doing so would leave all kinds of stray pointers into it after it's unloaded, leading to almost-certain crashes :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the module being in use, the inability to unload it could also be caused by a bug in the driver.

This problem occurred when a driver I was developing was missing the logic to unlink the `/dev` entry linkage structure during the driver unload operation.